# Update Next Step based on Opportunity Stage

Tags: opportunity, validation

I"m trying to put a validation rule in place that requests the "Next Step: to be filled if the Stage is changed. Currently the validation rule below works and ignores the request if the stage is set to closed lost, but it is not working for Closed Won.

For Clarity: If the stage name is changed please update the "Next Step" field, however if the Stage Name is changed to Closed Lost or Closed Won then it will ignore the Next Step Validation Rule.

```
AND( ISCHANGED( StageName ), NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep)), 
Probability<>0 || AND( ISCHANGED( StageName ),
NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep)), 
Probability<>100))
```

I added the OR option and it still does not work. Thoughts?

Comment: Use isWon as a exclusion instead of stage name or probability. Basically replace everything after the first line with isWon = false and a test for lost   False which I think is closed = true and isWon = false. Or you can simply used isclosed = false. Forget which ones need is infront of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be like this

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won') || ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Lost')),
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep))
)
```

Comment: Thank you Santanu, while it appears to be accurate. I'm still getting the notification to update the next step field on "Closed Won".  Even though in the validation rule you wrote it excludes it.

Comment: updated the rule, it should be `||` condition, instead of `&&`, I have tested this